# htacess rewrite require www with cloudfront CDN support

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have those two lines in htaccess to require www.*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #require www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oisie\.com
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.oisiecom%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I'm adding Amazon Web Services (AWS) CloudFront CDN and it's not working because of 301 redirects.

If I go straigt to

```
http://XXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/img/preloader.gif
```

I get redirected to my site's real domain e.g. oisie.com

How to miss www.* redirects when request is comming from *.cloudfront.net?

You can check for details at http://www.oisie.com/en

Comment: How can `XXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net` be redirected to `www.oisiecom` by this rule since rewrite condition is only redirecting `oisie.com`

Comment: Maybe cloudfront asks for css/gif/js files from oisie.com not from www.oisie.com and it gets redirected. That's why I'm asking this question here. I don't know. What I do know, is that no cloudfront url work for this site and I found out that it might be because of www redirects.

Comment: You can comment out this rule and retest.

Comment: already tried, it works w/o www rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot about this question already, but I've fixed the problem. I can't remember exact steps, what I've done, but now i have a subdomain for static contents - js, css etc. it points to same directory as it would be normal domain. eg:

```
http://s.oisie.com/img/oisie.png
```

is same url as

```
http://www.oisie.com/img/oisie.png
```

In Cloudfront configuration I'm using `s.oisie.com` domain and it works fine.

So the solution:
create virtualhost for static domain, which will be used by cloudfront and use it in cloudfront config (at AWS console).

hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it with below redirect rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301]
```